# Blender, convert .stl to .obj with prompt commande

Tags: python, blender, catia

I want to convert an .stl file to .obj, without using blender interface.

To do that, i want to do it in two step :

1 STL to BLEND

2 BLEND to OBJ

Actually BLEND to OBJ work ok with this python code :

```
import bpy
import sys


argv = sys.argv
argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:] # get all args after "--"

obj_out = argv[0]

bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=obj_out, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
```

and with this batch :

```
@echo off

rem Put the path of the blender folder
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender

set FILENAME=guitar.blend
set TARGET=guitar.obj
rem Launch
blender %FILENAME% --background --python convert_blend_to_obj.py -- %TARGET%


pause
```

This work perfectly.

The problem is with the STL to BLEND, its not working with this python code :

```
import bpy
import sys

argv = sys.argv
argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:] # get all args after "--"

blend_out = argv[0]

bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=blend_out, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
```

And the batch associated :

```
@echo off

rem Put the path of the blender folder
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender

set FILENAME=turbine.stl

set TARGET=turbine.blend

rem Launch
blender %FILENAME% --background --python convert_stl_to_blend.py -- %TARGET%


pause
```

i got as an error : File format is not supported in file C:..\turbine.stl
Blender quit

I think the problem is in my python code, but i don't know what to change.

I found help for the first script here : https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Wavefront_OBJ

I thank you in advance for the help, maybe there is a better way to that. I don't want to have to launch blender and do it manually. I only need a prompt commande.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i got as an error : File format is not supported in file C:..\turbine.stl Blender quit

The error you are getting means that Blender is trying to read first command argument as a .blend file. Just put your script's arguments after "--" (as it says in the script's comment), and it should work.

Made some changes to the script to import STL and export an OBJ in one step, to test if it works:

```
import bpy
import sys

argv = sys.argv
argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:] # get all args after "--"

stl_in = argv[0]
obj_out = argv[1]

bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_in, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=obj_out, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
```

and launched it as follows:

```
blender --background --python convert_stl_to_blend.py -- test.stl test.obj
```

Comment: sorry to say that, but this is not working. You can't go to stl to obj without passing to .blend. I don't understand what you try to did here

Comment: if I understood it correctly, you want to convert STL to OBJ, which means that your script has to (1) import an STL, (2) export an OBJ, which is what the script in my answer should do.

Comment: > blender %FILENAME% --background --python convert_stl_to_blend.py -- %TARGET%

the main problem is how you launch the script: **%FILENAME%** should go after the "--"

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code with the following input on OSX

```
/Applications/blender-2.77a-OSX_10.6-x86_64/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender --background --python convert_stl_to_blend.py -- fileIN.stl FileOut.obj
```

This code was very helpful, thanks guys!

BTW, I needed this code to do all files in the directory and they were numbers so I used the following code to have blender convert all the files for me:

```
import bpy
import sys

for x in range(1, 20):
    stl_in = str(x) +'.stl'
    obj_out = str(x) +'.obj'
    bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_in, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
    bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=obj_out, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
```